# Triangle inequality symbol

Tags: math-mode, symbols, stacking-symbols

Does anybody know what symbol to put above an inequality symbol `<` to indicate that the triangle inequality has been applied?

I would like a symbol like this (which is not in The Comprehensive Latex Symbol List)

[image: doesnt work]

And I tried the following

```
\mathrel{\triangle\!\!\!\!/}
```

but the two lines are not parallel:

[image: doesnt work]

Does anybody know how to somehow rotate the line to the correct angle? Any help is appreciated!

Comment: First, search https://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/info/symbols/comprehensive/

Comment: Do you use the triangle inequality so many times that you need a special symbol instead of simply adding the words? Such stenography is not really useful, in my opinion.

Comment: @egreg Yes, actually I do :). I don't like writing 'the triangle inequality' everywhere, but I really need to somehow show that it is being used.

Comment: Try `\mathrel{\ooalign{\hidewidth$\triangle$\hidewidth\cr\rotatebox[origin=c]{-9}{$/$}\cr}}`.

Comment: @HarishKumar Your solution works as well, thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a tikz picture

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\DeclareRobustCommand\trineg{%
\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline,scale=.07]
\draw (0,0) -- (4,0) -- (2,3.46410161514) -- cycle;
\draw [domain=1:3.4] plot(\x,{(5.6-3.46410161514*\x)/-2});
\end{tikzpicture}}
\begin{document}
$\mathrel{\triangle\!\!\!\!/}$ test \trineg\ test $\trineg $
\end{document}
```